# How do you mix Phusion Passenger in a mod_perl virtual host?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, catalyst

I have a VirtualHost which sets the handler for Location / to a PerlModule to deploy a catalyst application.

I want to convert the catalyst application to rails, but gradually.  The front end is all javascript using the ExtJS Framework, and the backend only serves JSON.  This will allow for a gradual transition as long as the JSON is in the same format from catalyst and rails.

Ideally I would be able to do by hosting both rails and catalyst on the same domain, and then update the pieces of my AJAX application to use rails instead of catalyst one at a time.

I need to have them on the same domain so I don't have to recode all of the AJAX components to use a script tag proxy and JSON Callback.

Any ideas on how to configure phusion passenger to work with mod_perl, which owns the location / and everything it contains unless I specify another handler?

I tried setting the default handler for /rails to default-handler to bypass mod_perl, and then using Passenger's RailsBaseURI /rails... but this obviously doesn't work.  You can't use RailsBaseURI in a Location tag. I wasn't able to find any handlers to use from passenger.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like some simple "Alias" directives are all you need.

```
Alias /still/catalyst /path/to/the/catalyst_fastcgi.pl/
```